# How to use Reflection with Spring MVC to create CRUD application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a basic Spring 3.0 MVC + Hibernate 4.0 CRUD app set up and running properly.

Lets say that tomorrow I decide to modify the attributes of my "User" entity.
(I now need to add age, sex, nickname, etc).

How could I create a jsp template that given a "User" object (passed through the ModelMap) would show all attributes (either for display, or as inputs for editing), without knowing in advance how many there are. I simply want to avoid the tedious work of modifying the view (manually) whenever I change the model.

I know how to do this using reflection on plain old POJO's and handcrafted JSP pages, but the answer seems to elude me under the MVC model.

I just need the right incantation to do:

```
  FOREACH attributeName IN UserClass
    display ${user.attributeName}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can directly iterate through the fields of a class in jsp.
But what you can do is prepare a list of fields in your controller, then add these to the model, and iterate through this list as follows:

```
  <c:forEach items="${objectFields}" var="item">
     <c:set var="colTxt">
        <spring:eval expression="item[column]" htmlEscape="false" />
     </c:set>
     ${colTxt}
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is one approach I though about, but was hoping for a cleaner solution that would work directly on the View.
I'll wait a couple of days to see if anyone comes up with it, and if not I'll mark as solved.